# implementing SQL Server database - fastest way to find values

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, search, output

I'm using a SQL Server on an internal share.

- Let's say I have one table called `Profiles`
- Those contain Customer Age, Name, ID; Setting ID as primary Key.
- Now I create a textBox for search on id, named searchBox.

When I input an `ID` into searchBox, what is the quickest method for finding the right Customer and printing the Age, Name and ID to another textBox? because i actually want to Implement in on the searchBox' textValue changed without getting a slow program.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: select * from Customer where Id = ...?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about millions of rows, make sure you have a clustered index on your primary key. That way you have a covering index for your query and you can get the data you seek pretty fast.